# Where has the main menu item gone?

Tags: discussion

We used to have a menu link called main on meta site where we could return to the main site. Cant see it now...

Where has it gone. Is there another way to traverse between the meta and main site?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can navigate back to the main site by using the StackExchange drop down on the left side of the menu bar.

[image]

Comment: I liked the old way much better.

Comment: @sfdc_ninja It does feel bit daft. You need to go to help to reach meta but to go back you have to go to all SE sites...

Comment: The new top bar was only recently launched and still being tweaked. So, yes, the meta-to-site-to-meta navigation is one of those areas that needs a bit of work.